# Connection was Reset or Application Pool stopped repeatedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have NO access to the server options, so I'm hoping someone can help guide me to some likely problems before the server guy can get back to me. My application was working fine last week until the application pool suddenly stopped. It was restarted by IT, and so I tried to load my page again. Application pool stopped again (receiving a 503 server error). It happened over and over and over again. They put me in my own application pool, and it is still happening, so it is obviously my application, but I have no idea why. I receive no error messages, the it guy says that he can't see any errors, either. I deleted (after copying to another location) all of my files and started building them up again. It shows me compilation errors telling me xxx file does not exist. I add the file, and it moves to the next error. When I finally fix the last error, I get a message (in Firefox) telling me that the connection was reset. I have no idea what is happening, and I can't see error messages anywhere. Is there somewhere that I should tell the IT guy to look? Any particular server logs that might let him know what is happening. As far as I can tell, it's happening magically, since no errors are showing up - so it is really hard for me to fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access, look in the server event logs to see what ASP errors are being generated.  There is usually something in there that will point you in the right direction.

If you can't figure it out from Googling the event log error, post it here and maybe I can help

Comment: So far, the only errors the IT guy has seen are the ones that I am able to see when I am building up the pages. As soon as it is built, the errors disappear, but I can't access anything. I will see if I can find other errors in the log files. THanks!